# how to select the latest data from a column of type varchar

Tags: php, mysql

table schema

```
name            no_form
----            -------
john            16-0101-001
ahmad           16-0101-004
michael         16-0101-005
raja            16-0101-006
jason           16-0101-009
budi            16-0101-011
```

how to query to select last record from "no_form"?

Comment: duplicate of this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191503/how-to-select-the-last-record-of-a-table-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to give the table an Auto Increment primary key and then you can sort and rely on that ID.

Comment: bad advice do not rely on bigger id means later(in time) instert,  save insertion time into a timestamp field

Comment: But unless you are talking a LOT of data surely a timestamp will be bigger than an auto increasing int? And from the off as opposed to later in time.