# Function SELECT that returns a row in SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-function

I want to create a function that gets the last record from my table, but it didn't work.

My code is :

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetLastReglement (@CT_Num VARCHAR(17))
RETURNS VARCHAR(17)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (1) * 
    FROM F_REGLEMENTT
    WHERE CT_Num=@CT_Num
    ORDER BY CT_Num DESC
RETURN @CT_Num
END
```

Thanks for your help

PS: I'm novice in SQL

Comment: is there any ID col on your table ?

Comment: You are limiting `CT_NUM` to a single value and then ordering by it.  Hence, it is a constant and any row with a matching value might be returned.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "last" row, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Your function doesn't make sense. Why do you even want a function to begin with? Please edit your question to include sample data and desired results.

Comment: yes, CT_Num is the ID.

Comment: 'i(t) didn't work' is not a problem description.

Comment: If you want to return a row then why don't you use inline table valued function.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid i didn't get it, could you please give me an exemple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select the last record of a table in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191503/how-to-select-the-last-record-of-a-table-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might require to use return table as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetLastReglement (@CT_Num varchar(17))
returns @rtTable table
(
    --columns in your table F_REGLEMENTT with datatype as below
    col1 nvarchar(50)
    ...
)
as
begin
    insert into @rtTable
    select top (1) * 
    from F_REGLEMENTT
    where CT_Num=@CT_Num
    order by CT_Num desc
return;
end
```

Comment: and if i want to return just the number of the bill, why this code don't work ?

`CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetLastFatt (@DO_Piece VARCHAR(9)
)
RETURNS varchar9 as RETURN (
  SELECT top (1) DO_Piece 
  FROM F_DOCENTETE
  WHERE DO_Type =6
  ORDER BY DO_Piece DESC
)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try below one to get last row based on some unique column value.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION GetRowData
(
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM F_REGLEMENTT ORDER BY CT_Num DESC 
)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You could use the MAX function instead of top(1)*

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLastReglement] ()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT * FROM [F_REGLEMENT] WHERE CT_NUM =
(SELECT MAX(CT_NUM) FROM [F_REGLEMENT])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the entire row instead of the CT_Num as follow:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetLastReglement (@CT_Num VARCHAR(17)
)
RETURNS TABLE as RETURN (
  SELECT top (1) * 
  FROM F_REGLEMENTT
  WHERE CT_Num=@CT_Num
  ORDER BY CT_Num DESC
)
END
```

Comment: I get this problem

Msg 156, Niveau 15, État 1, Procédure GetLastReglement, Ligne 24
Syntaxe incorrecte vers le mot clé 'AS'.
Msg 178, Niveau 15, État 1, Procédure GetLastReglement, Ligne 25
Une instruction RETURN avec une valeur de retour ne peut être utilisée dans ce contexte.