# Is there an SQL Standard Keyword similar to First only for Last

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know if there is a keyword similar to `fetch first` [provided here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) for selecting the last rows?

I know something similar can be done by changing the sorting from say ascending to descending and use that, but I want to avoid that for now.

Comment: The solution is to reverse the sort order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select the last record of a table in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191503/how-to-select-the-last-record-of-a-table-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `fetch last`.

One solution is to reverse the sort order . . . but that reverses the results.  So, two sorts are necessary:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by . . . desc
      offset 0 fetch first 10 rows only
     ) t
order by . . . asc;
```