# How to select the latest price for product?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table:

```
+----+------------+-----------+---------------+
| id | product_id |   price   |     date      |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 1  | 4          | 2000      | 2019-02-10    |
| 2  | 5          | 1600      | 2019-02-11    |
| 3  | 4          | 850       | 2019-02-11    |
| 4  | 5          | 1500      | 2019-02-13    |
+----+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

I need to get a list of unique product ids that are the latest (newest, in other word, bigger `date`) ones. So this is the expected result:

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| product_id |   price   |     date      |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 4          | 850       | 2019-02-11    |
| 5          | 1500      | 2019-02-13    |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Any idea how can I achieve that?

---

Here is my query:

```
SELECT id, product_id, price, MAX(date)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY product_id
-- ot selects the max `date` with random price like this:
    +------------+-----------+---------------+
    | product_id |   price   |     date      |
    +------------+-----------+---------------+
    | 4          | 2000      | 2019-02-11    |
    | 5          | 1600      | 2019-02-13    |
    +------------+-----------+---------------+
-- See? Prices are wrong
```

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191503/how-to-select-the-last-record-of-a-table-in-sql regards

Answer (score 3):

You could use a correlated subquery

```
select t1.* from table t1
where t1.date=( select max(date) from table t2
where t1.product_id=t2.product_id
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *from
table1 t1
where (t1.product_id, t1.date) in 
               (select t2.product_id, max(t2.date)
                from table1 t2
                where t1.product_id = t2.product_id                    
               )
```

Comment: You can remove the correlation by removing the where clause inside the subquery and use `group by product_id`.

Comment: yes i can either do that or remove `group by` from inner query. I already did the later. But which one will be better according to you?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `GROUP BY`.  Use a *filter*:

```
SELECT id, product_id, price, MAX(date)
FROM tbl
WHERE tbl.date = (SELECT MAX(t2.date)
                  FROM tbl t2
                  WHERE t2.product_id = tbl.product_id
                 );
```

With an index on `(product_id, date)`, this is probably the fastest method.

If you can have duplicates on a given date, you can resolve them with:

```
SELECT id, product_id, price, MAX(date)
FROM tbl
WHERE tbl.id = (SELECT t2.id
                FROM tbl t2
                WHERE t2.product_id = tbl.product_id
                ORDER BY t2.date DESC
                LIMIT 1
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a modern version of MySQL (8.0), you can use this:

```
select *
from (
        SELECT id
            , product_id
            , price
            , date
            , row_number() over (partition by product_id order by date desc) rn
        FROM tbl
) a
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is with the analytic function `first_value`

```
SELECT distinct product_id, 
    first_value(price) over (partition by product_id order by date desc) last_price, 
    first_value(date) over (partition by product_id order by date desc) last_date
FROM tbl
```