# how to fetch the last row element from my sql db?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch the last row element of my table to my homepage,where my table is updated daily from backend.
I am using the query for now is :

```
select COLUMN_NAME from TABLE_NAME order by COLUMN_NAME desc limit 1;
```

which is not fetching the values properly.
this query does not able to fetch values like : `*********`
and even not working properly.
I want a query which can fetch all the type of values which is present in the last row of my table.

Comment: If you want to fetch all the columns, use `SELECT *`

Comment: If that's not the solution, you haven't described the problem. Tables don't have a "last row", ordering is only based on a criteria you specify in the query.

Comment: solution to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191503/how-to-select-the-last-record-of-a-table-in-sql

Comment: Your question needs sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you mean by "last row element".

Answer (score 0):

In MsSQL you must use Top 1:

```
SELECT TOP 1 `ColumnName` FROM `tableName` ORDER BY `ID` DESC
```

While in MySQL the one you mentioned is correct if the second COLUMN_NAME pointing to id

```
SELECT `name` FROM `tableName` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```