# How to pick Last Non Direct source using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, analytics

I have following touch points:

```
Session Number  Source
1               direct
2               social
3               paid
4               direct
5               direct
6               direct
```

I need to pick the Last-Non Direct source… which is paid in this example (session 3).

Take into consideration that it can be cases that have just direct and then direct should be displayed. So basically we need to have the same as Google Analytics does : Last Non-Direct Attribution.

What SQL code can do that?

Answer (score 0):

For your example, this should work

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Your_Table] 
WHERE Source <> 'direct'
ORDER BY [Session Number] DESC
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191503/how-to-select-the-last-record-of-a-table-in-sql)

**EDIT1:**

```
SELECT * FROM [Your_Table] 
WHERE 
--checking if anything else except 'direct' exists, if so, take the last one non direct
(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Your_Table] WHERE source <> 'direct') AND source <> 'direct') 
OR 
--if nothing except direct doesn't exist, just take the last row
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [Your_Table] WHERE source <> 'direct')
ORDER BY [session number] DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: in this way it will exclude all direct sources. If there is just direct than it should show direct. If there were at least one paid than it will show paid. If lots of non-direct sources than Last Non-Direct.

Comment: @hiichaki Postgres does not support the "Select TOP ..." syntax.  So that option is not available. Leaving only your EDIT1  LIMIT option.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pick the Last-Non Direct source… which is paid in this example (session 3).

In Postgres you would use:

```
select t.*
from t
where Source <> 'direct'
order by session_number desc
limit 1;
```

Instead of `limit`, you can also use:

```
fetch first 1 row only
```

If you don't want filtering, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where Source <> 'direct'
order by (source = 'direct') asc,  -- put last
         session_number desc
limit 1;
```

Or if you just want the session number, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select coalesce( max(session_number) filter (where source <> 'direct'),
                 max(session_number)
from t;
```

Comment: in this way it will exclude all direct sources. If there is just direct than it should show direct. If there were at least one paid than it will show paid. If lots of non-direct sources than Last Non-Direct.