# How to fetch notifications from a table to session users

Tags: php, database, join

I've a project where I submitted all the records to `notification table`, now I want to fetch according to the `session_id`'s activity

Details: My project is Q&A question and answer platform, I've separate `tables` in my database for each activity. e.g, `questions`, `answers`, `question-upvote`, `answers-like`, `comments`, `comments-like`, etc. I also have a `table` for `notifications`, where there are `7 - Columns` exist. `id`, `date`, `byUser_id`, `source_id`, `alert`, `source_type`, and `status`.

Notifications Structure - Image Attached:
[image]

Now after insert records in `notifications` table, I want to fetch the records according to the session_id's content (if someone liked the `session_id`'s answer, how to fetch? That is my question.

Trying Query:

```html
SELECT id,byUser_id,source_id,alert,source_type
FROM `qa-notifications`
FULL JOIN `qa-questions` `qa-notifications`.`source_id` = `qa-questions`.`id`
WHERE `qa-question`.`user_id` = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
```

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to write a SQL query to return the results you need; if that is true, you should post the SQL table schema/definitions in Text format.

Answer (score 1):

By all means, i am no expert, but i'm trying to think along.

If i understand correctly, you want to fetch the last action done ( liked, replied etc)

in that case, you need to select the last row in the notifications table:

SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
([How to select the last record of a table in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191503/how-to-select-the-last-record-of-a-table-in-sql))
from there on out, fetch the data from the other tables with a JOIN.

Yet again, no expert on the case, post intended to help you progress to the solution.