# How to get the last row of a sql table (no id column)?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have never used SQL before until today. I'm trying to look at the last row of a table (the name of the table is `prices_table`). The table has 3 columns, `sid`, `prices`, `datetime`.

I read [How to select the last record of a table in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191503/how-to-select-the-last-record-of-a-table-in-sql) and tried to use the first answer:

```
SELECT * FROM prices_table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

but it gives the error:

```
SELECT * FROM prices_table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
ERROR:  column "id" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM prices_table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
                                                    ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "prices_table.sid"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "last"? Data is just stored, not in any particular order. If you mean by DateTime, then order by DateTime desc. If you mean by SID, then order by SID desc.

Comment: If your table doesn't have an `id` column then you can't order by it, replace `id` with the column you want to order the rows by, ie `SELECT * FROM prices_table ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: We can't guess which column you can use as a way to determine the "last" row. It's typical to have an auto-increment column, but if you don't have that, you'll have to choose a column that you know is effectively correlated to the order you want.

Comment: @Isolated Oh I thought the table had an order, but I do mean the most recent `datetime`. When I print the first 10 rows of the table, it shows `datetime` in ascending order so I think the table is already sorted based on `datetime`?

Comment: @pilchard Is it standard to have an `id` column? In some posts that I read on SQL, it seems the answers assume there's an `id` column even though I did not see OP mentioning it

Comment: There's no standard, but it's common.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running MySQL? This looks like a Postgres error message.

Comment: You can check by running this query: `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: with no order by specified, you cannot count on any particular order.  what order you see the rows in will depend on how mysql has decided to read them, which can change based on a number of factors.

Answer (score 2):

The order of a table is not guaranteed. It sounds like at least some of the rows are stored in order by your `datetime` column, but we can't assume all of them are.

To be sure, you should specify the order in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM prices_table ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: In words, is this saying "sort the table in decreasing order based on the datetime column, and then show the first row"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You may want to start by reading a book or a tutoral on MySQL (or whatever brand of software you're using, if it's not MySQL).